Notations in the book Quadratic and Hermitian Forms
I do not understand some notations in "Quadratic and Hermitian
Forms" by Winfried Scharlau.
Chapter 8.13 page 322 of this book said that
"The symmetric bilinear form
$$t:K[G]\times K[G]\to K,\ \  t(xy)=T(xy^*)$$
is called the canonical trace form on $K [G]$. We note that the elements
of G form an orthogonal basis and that
$$t\cong n \langle1,\cdots ,1 \rangle =n \times \langle n \rangle.$$"
Can anyone explain $t\cong n \langle1,\cdots ,1 \rangle =n \times \langle n \rangle$?
$t$ is a bilinear form, how is it possible to be isomorphic to a space?!
Note that this book mentioned "If $n$
is a natural number, $n \times \phi$ will denote the $n$-fold orthogonal sum of the quadratic space $\phi$."
